# How to extending C: drive volume with free space by using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I know I can use use Disk Management to extend the volume for C: drive to make the additional space available.

Or using Command line like below, but how do I write this in Powershell?

```
Diskpart
Select disk 0
Extend size=
Extend
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to resize it to the Maximum size it can be extended to:

```
$size = Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter C
Resize-Partition -DriveLetter C -Size $size.SizeMax
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of two lines and variable you can do this by single command ..

Resize-Partition -DriveLetter C -Size $(Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter C).SizeMax

Answer (score 0):

$MaxSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter c).sizeMax

Resize-Partition -DriveLetter c -Size $MaxSize

Above method is working without any issue.